# SystemVerilog to VHDL std_logic generic

Tags: generics, vhdl, system-verilog, modelsim, xilinx-ise

My problem is that I have to pass a `generic` from a SystemVerilog module to a VHDL entity of type `std_logic`, that will be directly used inside that entity in signal assignments.

```
entity foo is
    generic( my_generic : std_logic);
    port (...);
end foo;

architecture arc of foo is
...
begin
    my_signal <= not(my_generic);
    ...
end arc;
```

However, `my_signal` is always `'U'`, whatever type (`integer`, `std_logic`, `bit`, `reg`, `wire`) is the parameter in SV. The tool I'm using is Modelsim 10.3b. There are some workarounds, like declare it as an integer in VHDL and then cast it to a `std_logic_vector` of width 1, but I like to know if there is a smarter way. Am I missing something? Is it allowed to pass `std_logic` as a parameter? Can this also cause problems during synthesis with Xilinx ISE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use a boolean to boolean mapping, instead: `generic(my_generic: boolean);` and `my_signal <= '0' when my_generic else '1';`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you for the fast reply, the problem is that I have a lot of comparisons `if(my_signal = MY_GENERIC)then`, where my_signal has to be a std_logic, so make the generic a boolean is of no help...

Comment: I understand your point but I just suggested to first identify whether the problem comes from your VHDL code or from the Modelsim SystemVerilog to VHDL mapping. The simple experiment I suggest should help, I think.